# SharePoint 2010 search with multiple keywords, wildcards and Date range filter

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, fast-search

I want to accomplish the following tasks in SharePoint 2010 environment.

I want the following function to be implemented in SharePoint 2010 search results.

- User can include the operators OR & AND in the search string.
- User can state the period for searching documents. (Date range filter)
- Provision will be made for use of “wild cards” in the search criteria

how many of the above stated items are possible in SharePoint with Out of the Box support.?

how many of them needs customization? and if customization is required for it then what I have to follow ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

They are all supported. Check out the KQL reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911(v=office.14).aspx

Wildcards have to be appended manually per term, and only wildcards at the end of a term is supported.

Comment: can "Advance Search" help in this ?

Comment: can I use the "Refinement Panel" for this ?

Comment: Users can type this directly into the search box. (term1 OR term2) AND terms3 AND lastmodifiedtime:2010-01-01..2012-01-01 wildcard*