# How to Combine Search on SharePoint landing page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, search-results, sharepoint-search

[image]

How to search multiple combined search keywords using search box on SharePoint Online landing page?

Comment: Hi @user110062, did you try below solution? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `OR` operator to combine the search keywords in SharePoint Online search box.

**For Example**:

```
Steroids OR Medicines
```

This will return the search results related to either "Steroids" or "Medicines" keywords.

Check this Microsoft official documentation to see what all operators and options are available for SharePoint search using KQL: [SharePoint Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)

**Related Read**: [SharePoint 2010 search with multiple keywords, wildcards and Date range filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160557/sharepoint-2010-search-with-multiple-keywords-wildcards-and-date-range-filter)

Comment: If an answer has been helpful, please consider accepting the answer to help increase visibility of this question for other members of the community.