# Partial search in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, search-results, administration

Does SharePoint search engine support partial words?

I'm asking because mine not, and I wanted to know whether is that particularly my issue alone, or is it just how it was built?

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint Online supports wild card search or free-text search using KQL queries in search.

**For example**: The following KQL queries return content items that contain the terms "federated" and "search":

- federated search
- federat* search
- search fed*

KQL queries don't support prefix matching with the wildcard `*` as prefix.

You can also search by property column names, using AND/OR operators, etc.

You can find detailed information in the Microsoft official documentation at:

1. [SharePoint Search - Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)
2. [Building search queries in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint)

**Related thread**: [How to Combine Search on SharePoint landing page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309818/how-to-combine-search-on-sharepoint-landing-page/309819#309819)